# how to count special character in a string

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String Functions how to count delimiter in string line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238184/string-functions-how-to-count-delimiter-in-string-line)

> I have a string as str = "one$two$three$four!five@six$" now how to count Total number of "$" in that string using java code.

Comment: You can get more ideas from this one: [Occurences of substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurences-of-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using replaceAll:

```
    String str = "one$two$three$four!five@six$";

    int count = str.length() - str.replaceAll("\\$","").length();

    System.out.println("Done:"+ count);
```

Prints:

```
Done:4
```

Using **replace** instead of **replaceAll** would be less resource intensive. I just showed it to you with **replaceAll** because it can search for **regex** patterns, and that's what I use it for the most.

Note: using **replaceAll** I need to escape **$**, but with **replace** there is no such need:

```
str.replace("$");
str.replaceAll("\\$");
```

Comment: both are correct ,, thank u very much for both of u,, i use second method,, its easy

Answer (score 3):

You can just iterate over the `Characters` in the string:

```
    String str = "one$two$three$four!five@six$";
    int counter = 0;
    for (Character c: str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c.equals('$')) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s1 = "one$two$three$four!five@six$";

String s2 = s1.replace("$", "");

int result = s1.length() - s2.length();
```